# Will Nvidia Proprietary Drivers work or should I use Manually installed CUDA for Ubuntu 12.04 & Blender 2.64?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, cuda

I am currently running the Manually installed Nvidia 64-295.49 CUDA drivers in 12.04LTS with my GeForce GTX 560 Ti, mainly for Blender 2.64 GPU rendering, but each time the Kernel updates I have to reinstall the driver. It's not difficult, but without some valuable time spent I never know if I'm using the latest version.

I am wondering if I could just use the recommended "NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library" that appears in the Additional Drivers dialog. Will it support CUDA? Has anyone had any success with it? ( I could try it and see, but It could lead to several hours trying to recover from failed attempt that I cannot afford to spare. )

Alternatively, how can I simplify the process of updating and reinstalling the NVIDIA CUDA driver.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insure that you receive all Nvidia updates without need to reinstall them each time kernel updates use PPA below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Regarding Nvidia Cuda. By default it is not supported so even if you install the Nvidia drivers CUDA doesn't work. You have to install CUDA manually. Simple search in google or use this tutorial
http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I've been using Ubuntu for several years now and I'm comfortable with the current situation, but I was hoping that something had changed. ( BTW - I've shared that same link with others asking how to install CUDA in the first place. Personally I have it printed out within arms reach. )